# How to save a layout as PDF on QGIS without author's name

Tags: qgis, layouts, pdf

Is there a way we can save a layout as a `PDF` and keep it anonymous ?

[image]

Here, when I check the document properties in Adobe Acrobat DC, I can see my full computer name with the QGIS version as well.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When exporting the PDF make sure, that you don't select the "Export RDF metadata" option:

[image]

Which leads to this

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. Have a nice day ;)

Comment: @abokey you are very welcome :)